# How to calculate all by all set intersections using redis?

Tags: redis

Is there a standard approach for returning all by all set intersections using redis?

For example, using the data below I would like to return the number of members in common between all sets, 3 comparisons in total

```
HMSET cset_details:1 name 'set 1' description 'my first set' date 'today'
HMSET cset_details:2 name 'set 2' description 'my second set' date 'today'
HMSET cset_details:2 name 'set 3' description 'my third set' date 'today'
SADD cset_members:1 a b c d
SADD cset_members:2  c d e
SADD cset_members:3 d e f g
```

Thanks

Iain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `SINTER` and `SINTERSTORE` commands (see http://redis.io/commands/sinter and http://redis.io/commands/sinterstore)

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SADD cset_members:1 a b c d
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SADD cset_members:2 c d e
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SADD cset_members:3 d e f g
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SINTER cset_members:1 cset_members:2 cset_members:3
1) "d"
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SINTERSTORE in_all_sets cset_members:1 cset_members:2 cset_members:3
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SMEMBERS in_all_sets
1) "d"
127.0.0.1:6379[1]>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't realize that this type of calculation would be handled mainly by the client. As an FYI, I am using R with rredis and rcppredis